# Using setInterval more basic for php code

Tags: javascript, php

Hello guys I have 2 question for you!

**1)** Lets make a sample; in database;

*user_id    user_x   user_ y*         exist.

And I have a abc.php file which is get the all user_id in database and update all the user_x user_y rows.To execute this abc.php i have a oto.php and it has setInterval js.So oto.php runs abc.php every 3 seconds and execute the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function(){
    $('#show2').load('abc.php')
},3000); 
        } );
</script>
```

Wow I already 2 file for one request....How can I make this situation more simple?

**2**) So we update the user_x and user_y but now we have to get this datas every 3 sec. So again I create a file called hop.php and I get this user_x user_y datas to php.It listed like user_x=24  user_y=59. Then i need to show this data to user as real time while these are increasing. So i created index.php and again use this js.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#show').load('hop.php')
    },3000); 
            } );
        </script>
```

and create a div#show and listed to screen.BUT i wanna list them different place on page.I mean i need to get user_x and user_y data separately and again update them 3 sec.(because oto.php increase these values in database so i need to show these value without reflesh)

How can i get these values separately so that i can put them everywhere i want...

Thanks for help!